# Solution Import not always updating display changes

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a managed solution that I am importing into an organisation as an update to the previous solution. In this update I am changing some display elements, such as where a subgrid is located on a form.

After importing the solution I go to the form and the grid has been moved to the new location but it also still exists in the old location, effectively duplicating the subgrid on the form.

Is there a particular reason why this is happening? I've tried into different organisations and its doing the same thing there too. It appears like it is merging the old and new solutions together rather than taking the latest changes, but I can't think why it would be doing this.

Comment: are the version numbers different? and do you have any unmanaged changes that might be colliding with this?

Comment: I had this exact problem when playing about with managed/unmanaged solutions. Trying to add managed on top of an unmanaged.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure to distribute both the old one and the new one as unmanaged.
- Make sure that the version number of the new one is higher than the old one.
- Make sure that the schema name of the component is the same in both versions.
- Make sure that you publish all changes (see [this possible issue](http://konradviltersten.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/publishing-customizations-doesnt-take-effect-in-crm-on-line/)).

Comment: @glosrob Good question! That's actually a hint I got from our MVP on CRM. He was at the summit a few weeks ago and they recommended it based on the gain in flexibility to outweigh the downside of un-packaget-ness. Basically, the likelihood of conflicts at a client's server when installing different solution from various providers is significant. And it's easier to remedy those if the solutions are "open". Feel free to question the standpoint as I don't agree fully with that opinion myself either.

Comment: I don't know enough either way, but was under impression managed solutions were more widely used. Think just means I need to do more reading+research

Comment: In a situation where a solution won't collide with an other, managed is to be preferred. But that's seldom the case. The problem may arise when different solutions alter the same entity (or even worse, the same field on an entity). Also, the order of importing/removing can be of significance.